# How can I change the size of the chapter name in the header and not make it bold? It is only working for the university name

Tags: pdftex, header-footer

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[top=1.5in,bottom=1in,left=2in,right=1in,asymmetric,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{\bf \Large Introduction}
\newpage

\subsection{\large Problem Statement}

\fancyhead{}

\fancyfoot{}

\fancyhead[LO]{\scriptsize{University name}}

\fancyhead[RE]{\sffamily{\nouppercase{\scriptsize{\leftmark}}}}

end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you expand your code in order to get a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: How? Can you please explain it?

Comment: Edit your question, so that it contains a LaTeX document that can be compiled.

Comment: I have done it. I have excluded the text under introduction and problem statement section and subsection respectively to avoid lengthy code.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can you help?